# Preventing the horizontal scrollbar from displaying? (C#)

Tags: c#, user-controls, pinvoke, scrollbar

Is there a way (perhaps with P/Invoke) to ***guarantee*** that the horizontal scrollbar will *never* appear in a usercontrol? It seems that even when i have the autoscroll property set to false, it displays sometimes.

Comment: Did you try `HScroll = false`?

Comment: I think AutoScroll property works enough

Comment: I got your problem See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your form is setting UserControl with old properties.

So you have to do this

- change back `UserControl.AutoScroll=False;`
- Rebuild your application
- Redrag your UserControl on the place of Old One

**Explanation:**
When you drag your UserControl at that time The Designer set the properties in FormDeginer (**check your Form Deginer**) 
Now after changing properties of your UserControl,and then adding it is set by new Properties for new Control instance but didn't change of old ones...

Comment: That is not the answer, im adding my UserControl programatically. So the designer is not doing anything.

Comment: So, at the time you are adding your user control just add UserControl_name.AutoScroll=false;

Comment: The code is very large. very complicated UserControl, one id rather not give away - but basically, im setting the autoscroll property to false, and just adding/removing its vertical scrollbar when needed, and the horizontal still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `this.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;`?

Comment: Even setting that to false, when i add a control with a greater width than my control it displays.

Comment: Also try setting the `MaximumSize` property if you're adding bigger controls.

Answer (score 0):

For some controls you can set the ScrollBars attribute to what you want. This is an example for a rich text box you may find useful (you may find one for what you are inheriting from), in initialisation set:

```
rtbText.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical
```

For containers you can use the HScrollProperties, which you can set the Enabled/Disabled on containers.
E.g. To have no Horizontal Scrollbar on a container.

```
userControlInstance.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = False;
```